# Launch Python script in Git Bash

Tags: python, git

I'm writing git commands through a Python script (on Windows)
When I double click on `myScript.py`, commands are launched in the Windows Command Prompt.
I would like to execute them in Git Bash.

Any idea how to do that without opening Git Bash and write `python myScript.py`?

Comment: If it is windows, just typing `myscript.py` would work

Answer (score 2):

You can create a batch file (.bat) with the following content:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -c "python myScript.py"
```

Yu can also make this available for all .py file by editing your regedit as explained here: [Adding a context menu item in Windows for a specific file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597700/adding-a-context-menu-item-in-windows-for-a-specific-file-extension) with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -c "python \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

in the top of your python file add `#!/usr/bin/python` then you can rename `mv myScript.py myScript` and run `chmod 755 myScript`. This will make it so you can run the file with `./myScript` look into adding the file directory to your path or linking it to the path if you want to be able to run it from anywhere.