# Adding a context menu item in Windows for a specific file extension

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, custom-contextmenu

I am trying to add a context menu item to a DLL file. The reason is that I have written an application which retracts and deployed a managed DLL file to the GAC. The application is all good, but now I want the ability to right-click a DLL and just click "copy to GAC".

I've tried to follow instructions as per this question: [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders) but to no avail. When I right click a DLL, nothing new is appearing.

I've also tried the following: https://winaero.com/blog/add-register-dll-context-menu-commands-for-dll-files-in-windows-10/#comment-22928 - ran the reg file but no result as well.

Maybe there's a hardcoded restriction on DLL files for such actions?

Here's my current registry setup:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Read Microsoft's documentation, this is all explained: [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers)

Answer (score 13):

This is based on andromeda947's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762):

If you have admin rights you can use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.yourextension`, which is simpler as it doesn't require an intermediate ProgID.

## Option 1: edit the registry manually

1. add a new key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.yourextension\shell\your menu entry text\command` creating any keys you need to in that path (if there's not one for `.yourextension` add it; if there's not one for `shell` add it; etc)
2. set the default value for `command` (the last key you created) to `C:\path\to\yourapp.exe "%1"`

## Option 2: I made a tool to do this

you can download it [here](https://github.com/9072997/regwincontext/releases). This is an example of how to register notepad.exe as a context menu item for dll files.

```
regwincontext.exe dll "notepad it" C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Comment: Nice utility. Just a suggestion, update the comment above to use double quotes vs. single.  The single quotes will show up in the context menu. 

regwincontext.exe dll "notepad it" C:\Windows\notepad.exe

Comment: Is it possible to add a sub menu?  (i.e. multiple options that pop out as a submenu).  For example "Dll Tools -> 1. view, 2. analyze, 3, etc...."  NEVER MIND JUST FOUND IT:https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270985/1502289

Answer (score 11):

The general steps to achieve this are as follows:

1. Fire up `regedit`
2. Identify the ProgID for your extension - go to `HKCR\.yourextension` and take note of the default value (in your case, `dllfile`)
3. Navigate to `HKCU\Software\Classes` (for user) or `HKLM\Software\Classes` (for all users)
4. Look for a matching key (in your case `dllfile`) - if it's not there, create it
5. Ensure it has a sub-key called `shell`
6. Add a sub-key to `shell` named as the command you want (refer to image below)
7. Add a sub-key to your new key called `command`
8. Modify the `(Default)` value to be the command you want to execute. `%1` will give you the path of the file in context (remember to wrap it in `"` due to potential white-space in the path)

You seem to have done all the above, so you may be doing something wrong, as this is my result after a quick sanity test:

[image]

So, here are a few things I can think of that would make it behave non-intuitively:

- You're adding this to `HKLM` rather than `HKCU` - due to how inheritance works, I do believe adding it to `HKLM` would require a restart, or at best, a shell restart
- You've added this to `HKCU` but your dll requires elevated permissions to access
- You have some silly syntax error somewhere ;)

The sample command I used to test this was a good old boring `"C:\Windows\notepad.exe" "%1"`