# How do I create the OpenAPI section for the 404 page?

Tags: swagger, http-status-code-404, openapi

I'm using [OpenApi 3](https://swagger.io/specification/). A tool I use, [Owasp Zap](https://www.zaproxy.org/) looks at the OpenAPI doc and creates fake requests. When it gets a 404, it complains that it doesn't have the media type that the OpenAPI promises.

But I didn't write anything in the OpenAPI doc about how 404s are handled. Obviously I can't write an infinite number of bad end points & document that they return 404s.

What is the right way to record this in the OpenAPI yaml or json?

Here is a minimal yaml file... I know for sure that this file does say anything about 404, ie. 404s aren't in the contract so tools are complaining that 404s are valid responses, but 404 is what a site should return when a resource is missing

```yaml
---
"openapi": "3.0.0"

paths:
    /Foo/:
        get:
            responses:
                "200":
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Foo"
                default:
                    description: Errors
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
    schemas:
        Foo:
            type: object
            required:
                - name
            properties:
                name:
                    type: string
        Error:
            type: object
            required:
                - error
            properties:
                error:
                    type: string
                message:
                    type: string
                data:
                    type: object
```

Comment: Can this be a problem with the webserver where you host your API?

Comment: Problem could be anything. For what it's worth, it is a python app--  connexion on top of flask.

Comment: The wording seemed a bit unclear: is ZAP generating requests following the schema (i.e. using the paths specified) or random paths as well? The latter case would seem more like a problem with the tool — you could add a `/` path with a 404 response but that seems kludgey, especially since OpenAPI only allows one level of pattern matching (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892)

Comment: @ChrisAdams - It also generates endpoints like admin.php and then complains that it got a 404.  I'll try that, I guess it is the equivalent of "/{Param}" where {Param} is nonexistent endpoints.

Comment: It would definitely be nice when the enhancement to OpenAPI lands since you could document e.g. a common error format but I would class that as as defect in ZAP: if it does something the API contract does not say it can do and gets the standard status code in return, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been proposed already but not implemented: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/521

In the comments someone gave a suggestion: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/521#issuecomment-513055351, which reduces a little your code, but you would still have to insert N*M entries for N paths * M methods.

Since we don't have the ability to make the specification change to our needs, all that remains is we adapting ourselves.

From your profile, you seem to be a windows user. You can for example, create a new explorer context menu to your `.yaml` files ([Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype), [Adding a context menu item in Windows for a specific file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597700/adding-a-context-menu-item-in-windows-for-a-specific-file-extension)), and make it run a script that auto-fills your file.

Here, an example python script called `yamlfill404.py` that would be used in the context call in a way like `path/to/pythonexecutable/python.exe path/to/python/script/yamlfill404.py %1`, where `%1` is the path to the file being right clicked.

Python file:

```py
import yaml
from sys import argv
import re

order = ['openapi','paths','components']
level0re = re.compile('(?<=\n)[^ ][^:]+')

def _propfill(rootnode, nodes, value):
    if len(nodes) == 1:
        rootnode[nodes[0]] = value
    if len(nodes) > 1:
        nextnode = rootnode.get(nodes[0]) 
        if rootnode.get(nodes[0]) is None:
            nextnode = {}
            rootnode[nodes[0]] = nextnode
        _propfill(nextnode, nodes[1:], value)

def propfill(rootnode, nodepath, value):
    _propfill(rootnode, [n.replace('__slash__','/') for n in nodepath.replace('\/','__slash__').split('/')], value)

def yamlfill(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        yamltree = yaml.safe_load(file)
    #propfill(yamltree, 'components/schemas/notFoundResponse/...', '')
    propfill(yamltree, 'components/responses/notFound/description', 'Not found response')
    propfill(yamltree, 'components/responses/notFound/content/application\/json/schema/$ref', '#/components/schemas/notFoundResponse')
    responses = [mv['responses'] if 'responses' in mv else [] for pk,pv in (yamltree['paths'].items() if 'paths' in yamltree else []) for mk,mv in pv.items()]
    for response in responses:
        propfill(response, '404/$ref', '#/components/responses/notFound')
    yamlstring = yaml.dump(yamltree)
    offsets = [i[1] for i in sorted([(order.index(f.group(0)) if f.group(0) in order else len(order),f.start()-1) for f in [f for f in level0re.finditer('\n'+yamlstring)]])]
    offsets = [(offset,(sorted([o for o in offsets if o > offset]+[len(yamlstring)-1])[0])) for offset in offsets]
    with open(filepath[:-5]+'_404.yaml', 'w') as file:
        file.write(''.join(['\n'+yamlstring[o[0]:o[1]] for o in offsets]).strip())

yamlfill(argv[-1])
```

It processes the `%1`, which would be `path/to/original.yaml` and saves it as `path/to/original_404.yaml` (but you can change it to overwrite the original).

This example script changes the yaml formating (quotes type, spacing, ordering etc), because of the library used `pyyaml`. I had to reorder the file with the `order = ['openapi','paths','components']`, because it loses ordering. For less instrusion, maybe a more manual insertion would be better suited. Maybe one that uses only regex. Maye using `awk`, there are plenty of ways.

Unfortunately it is just a hack not not a solution.